# What does class_getClassVariable() do?

Tags: objective-c, class, metaclass, objective-c-runtime, class-variables

If instance variables belong to an instance of a class, class variables would belong to an instance of a metaclass, I should think. But my experience with the Objective-C metaclass tells me that this is unlikely.

I'm wondering what `class_getClassVariable` does as opposed to `class_getInstanceVariable`, and why there is not a `class_setClassVariable` in the runtime.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found a discussion about it here:
http://lists.apple.com/archives/objc-language/2008/Feb/msg00021.html

> Nope, it's not possible. There is no compiler support, and there is no
>   runtime support; `class_getClassVariable(cls, name)` merely calls
>   `class_getInstanceVariable(cls->isa, name)`.
>
> If it were possible, it likely would not give you a new variable on
>   each subclass anyway. Objective-C's metaclasses are not quite first-
>   class enough for that to work well.

Answer (score 1):

The class_getClassVariable() function doesn't make sense, because there's no such thing as a class variable in Objective C.

My guess is that class variables are supported by the runtime, but not by the language.